# Http POST for a form not working in iOS

Tags: ios, forms, authentication, post, asihttprequest

I am trying to login into a webpage through an iPhone app. I tried using both ASIFormDataRequest and NSURLConnection but am unable to get through the login process successfully. Below is the HTML form code and my iOS code:

```
<form action="login.chi">
<div id="login">
<div id="login-form">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Username</td>
  <td><INPUT NAME="username" VALUE=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Password</td>
  <td><INPUT NAME="password" VALUE="" TYPE="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" nowrap align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Login">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div></form>
```

My app code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/login.chi"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"password"];

[request startSynchronous];
```

It posts the data and returns a HTTP status code = 200 but does not complete the authentication. I wiresharked it to see if the POST was right and it seemed right. Please advice what I am missing.. Thanks..

**UPDATE:**

I looked at the wireshark captures more closely and saw that it was landing on an intermediate page that had the information of the URL that needs to be sent for successful authentication..the response is shown below:

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://ip_address:port/login?username=test&response=588ba0bd013e5f4873b46ff96e165e4a&userurl=http://www.google.org/"/>
</head></html>
```

The content in the meta tag contains the 'url' that I need to connect to to complete the authentication. Normally a browser would do it automatically but I am not able to understand how to handle in the app.. Should I parse the response string and extract the url from it? Is that the way to go? Please suggest..

Comment: Did you get the right url - what's the <form action=...> bit in the html? You may need to include the login button in the form data as well, they server may be expecting it.

Comment: Updated the code to reflect the action in the form..

Answer (score 0):

Your form is posting to `login.chi` but your Objective-C code is posting to `/login`.  You need the correct, full path.

Comment: Thanks Jim..I had it right in the code, but missed it here.. I made some progress though and updated my question..